# Redeploy locally installed artifact to a remote repository

Tags: maven

I have a Maven artifact (javax.activation as it happens) that I installed manually in  my local repository some time in the past. I don't remember where it came from, but it appears not to be available from any of the public repositories.

I have access to a shared remote repository for my team. How can I redeploy this artifact to the remote repository? I found the `deploy:deploy-file` goal but that appears to be for files not already managed by Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* use `deploy:deploy-file`.

The fact that it is in your local repo already shouldn't be an issue.  It's in fact even easier.  Since you already have a pom for your artifact, you can specify `-DpomFile` when deploying (assuming you're not trying to deploy a pom).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the artifact files from your repository to the remote one.

Your repository is stored in `~/.m2/repository`. Copy the `javax/activation` folder from one repository to the other.

Comment: I suppose I could do that but it would be convenient to let Maven create the necessary folder structures, update the index and such.

Comment: What do you mean in your question by remote repository? I'm not sure I understood exactly what you meant anymore.

Comment: I mean a remote Maven repository in the usual sense at http://some-site.com/maven2/ I would like to be able to deploy an artifact there, which is already installed in my local machine.